# Múltiplas condições em um if

Tags: c, condição

Estou com um código aqui, e preciso colocar várias condições dentro de um IF.

No caso preciso colocar dessa maneira:

```
if (X->meia != 's' || X->meia != 'S' || X->meia != 'N' || X->meia != 'n')
{
   printf("\nDigite S ou N!!\n");
}
```

Mas dessa maneira a condição não está funcionando. Como faço?

Answer (score 4):

Use `&&`:

```
if (X->meia != 's' && X->meia != 'S' && X->meia != 'N' && X->meia != 'n')
{
   printf("\nDigite S ou N!!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Deviam ser `&&` em vez de `||`.

Se fossem as barras bastava um condição ser verdadeira para printar a mensagem.
Ou seja, se `meia` for um `n` a mensagem é printada pois `n != s`.

Se fossem os `&&` é necessário que sejam todos verdadeiros para a mensagen ser printada, isto é, o caráter não ser `n` ou `s`.